# How can I combine rows based on two columns matching in KQL?

Tags: azure, kql, azure-log-analytics

I am trying to get a number of rows combined within a table in a KQL log analytics query.
My current query result, or input table, is this:

| id | name | InstanceId | MonthlyPreTaxCost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | vm-for-oe-ip | 0.247 |
|  |  | vmtest-ip | 0.263 |
| test-orphaned-ip | test-orphaned-ip |  |  |
| vmTest-ip | vmTest-ip |  |  |

What I want, is a result that contains only a single record: vmTest-ip as the id, the name, and then the MonthlyPreTaxCost associated with that id:

| id | name | InstanceId | MonthlyPreTaxCost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| vmTest-ip | vmTest-ip | vmtest-ip | 0.263 |

I initially thought I should do this using a self join, but I cannot get the condition check (id == InstanceId) right. Inner joining on itself, for example, gives this:

| id | name | InstanceId | MonthlyPreTaxCost | id1 | name1 | InstanceId1 | MonthlyPreTaxCost1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | vmtest-ip | 0.263 | test-orphaned-ip | test-orphaned-ip |  |  |
|  |  | vm-for-oe-ip | 0.247 | test-orphaned-ip | test-orphaned-ip |  |  |
|  |  | vmtest-ip | 0.263 | vmTest-ip | vmTest-ip |  |  |
|  |  | vm-for-oe-ip | 0.247 | vmTest-ip | vmTest-ip |  |  |

How can I achieve my desired result?

Comment: Can you provide data in text format not in images and what is your input table and how do you expect your output table to be as example would be good

Comment: @RithwikBojja Yes, on it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be quite simple: change the condition check to be non-case sensitive (=~ instead of ==). This fixed my problem.